# Getting HTTP Response value on submission page

Tags: php, json, api, http-headers, httpresponse

I have a basic form that POSTs to a url that speaks to an API. The API then sends back a response that looks like this:
`{"url":"/hospitals/3780/appointments/70132614/confirmation?reservation_code=1557959700"}`

I just need to grab the URL response value, do some parsing and use in CURL.

**How do you grab this from the HTTP Response? I've searched for days. No luck.**

Thanks!

Comment: It is JSON, so it should be easy to parse.

Comment: How would I grab the values from the HTTP Response? I'm new to that piece of it.

Comment: You would use `json_decode()` which would make an array. From there `$my_variable['url']` would contain the result.

Comment: Once I get a response on the page, I don't know how to use json_decode() to grab that response data from the header. I typically only work with the DOM, so grabbing and manipulating data in the header is super new to me. Thanks for the help, Jay!

Comment: Glad to help Ryan!